# Domain configured in LAMP gets redirect 301

Tags: wordpress, apache, localhost, lamp, ubuntu-22.04

I`m using LAMP in Ubuntu 22.04 for setting up Wordpress sites. After configuring new website with new IP and domain name in /etc/hosts file, I get 301 redirect form http://www.domain-2.com to http://www.domain-1.com on my localmachine.

**/etc/hosts** file content:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.2 www.domain-1.com
127.0.0.3 www.domain-2.com
```

**/etc/apache2/site-available/domain-2.conf** file content:

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
    ServerName domain-2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain-2.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain-2
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR)/access.log combined
    
    <Directory /var/www/domain-2/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After configuring .conf file I did below things by sudo privileges:

- a2enmod rewrite is enable,
- apache2ctl configtest shows that syntax is OK
- site was enabled by a2ensite domain-2.conf
- systemctl was reload by systemctl reload apache2

To fix the issue I tried to:

- clear cache of the web browser,
- restarting apache2,
- reload apache2,
- make new file .conf,
- /bin/systemctl restart systemd-hostnamed,
- delete empty .htaccess file,
- add default Wordpress content to .htaccess file,

I still get 301 redirect from domain-2.com to domain-1.com but URL http://www.domain-2.com/phpmyadmin is reachable. What else I can do to get rid of this 301 responde code and make domain-2.com reachable on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I made mistake in configuring .conf file. It should be <VirtualHost *:80> not <VirtualHost *.80>